# How to access to the all children's dynamically?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have json with some products, sorted in categories, example:

```
{
  "Shoes": [
    { "title": "Product One", "price": 100 ... },
    ....
  ],
  "Hats": [
    { "title": "Product 23", "price": 12.2 ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Then, loadit like this:

saved to the StreamingAssets/products.json.

```
public class Products {
    public List<Shoes> Shoes;
    public List<Hats> Hats;

    public static Products CreateFromJSON(string json) {

        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "products.json");
        if (File.Exists(filePath)) {
            string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            Products p = JsonUtility.FromJson<Products>(dataAsJson);
            return p;
        }

        Debug.Log("Missing JSON file: " + filePath);
        return null;
    }
}


public class Shoes: Model { }

public class Hats: Model { }

public class Model {
    public string title;
    public int price;
    public string sprite;
    ...
}
```

this work fine, load/parse..., but

I want to access dynamically to the Products, to be able to iterate through `Products`, something like this in `foreach` loop `Products[nameOfsubCategory][0].title`.

Currently implementation is working `Products.Shoes[0].title` but this is no good practice and no sense.

Comment: Have you tried loading it into a dictionary<String,Model> ?

Comment: Yes, but is nothing better...

Comment: if your data is string+Model, as it stands your choices are limited. You dont need the shoes/hats class, just a string and model

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq): you can do things like `products.Where(p=>p.price>100)` and a lot of other things.